# Haskell function to test if Int is perfect square using infinite list

Tags: haskell

Purely for pleasure, and practice, I am trying to write a simple Haskell function to determine if an integer is a perfect square. Now I know that there are other solutions out there but I am wondering if there is a way to do it with an infinite list. I've started with this, but for clear reasons, it is not working (it never stops!)

```
    isSquare :: Integer -> Bool
    isSquare n = sum[ 1 | x <- [1..], x*x == n] /= 0
```

Also, if I might add, can someone point out how to search an infinite list for the first instance of something and then STOP! ?

Comment: You want to continue checking the next element in the list until your number / list number < 0

Comment: The problem is that `sum` is strict; it consumes the entire list before returning. One way of making sure the function terminates is to supply it with a finite list: `x <- [1..n]` will only test numbers `<= n`.

Comment: @Telthien - do you mean < 1?

Comment: @poorsod Whoops. That's a stupid mistake. Yeah

Answer (score 11, accepted):

About the infinite search function:

There is already a function that searches a list for a value - `elem`.

If you assume the infinite list is sorted, we could write a version of elem that works on such a list. This can easily be accomplished by firstly rejecting any elements less than the search value. The first value not rejected then must be either equal to or greater than the search element. If equal - return true, else return false

```
infiniteElem1 :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
infiniteElem1 x list = (== x) $ head $ dropWhile (< x) list
```

Example usage:

```
> infiniteElem1 10 [1..]
True
> infiniteElem1 10 [1,3..]
False
```

There is one problem though with `infiniteElem1` though: If used on a finite list, it may throw an exception if the element isn't found:

```
> infiniteElem1 100 [1,2,3]
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

This is a reason the function `head` is best avoided. A better solution is this:

```
infiniteElem :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
infiniteElem x list = case dropWhile (< x) list of
  [] -> False
  (v:_) -> v == x
```

Now it works with a finite sorted list as well:

```
> infiniteElem 100 [1,2,3]
False
```

With this your problem becomes trivial:

```
let isSquare n = n `infiniteElem` [ x * x | x <- [1..]]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `takeWhile` or `dropWhile`. For example:

```
isSquare n = head (dropWhile (< n) squares) == n
  where squares = [x*x | x <- [0..]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, using Sum on an infinite list will not work. In particular, how can you ever know that every future element of the list is going to be zero? You can't, so you have to get the whole list before calculating the sum. For an infinite list, this can take a little while.

If you really want to use an infinite list--infinite lists *are* fun, after all--I suggest constructing an infinite list of square numbers. Then check whether `n` is in that list. You have to be a bit clever about how you do this to ensure it terminates, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. (Man, I love that phrase :P.)

You can find something from an infinite list using a function like, predictable, `find`. This will actually stop as soon as it finds something. However, if it *doesn't* find the element, it will never stop. This may not be the behavior you desire. There's no general way of getting around this, but you can figure out how to fix it for any particular problem: for example, if the list is sorted in ascending order, you can do `takeWhile (< limit)` where `limit` is the upper bound on the possible answer.

Comment: Well I suppose the limit is the number I'm inputting to find if it's a square. It's square root can't be more than it eh.

Answer (score 4):

```
let isSquare n = elem n (takeWhile (<=n) [ x*x | x <- [1..]])
ghci> isSquare 25
True
ghci> isSquare 28
False
```

Comment: Great! But how does this stop and not go on forever?

Comment: takeWhile x takes all elements from a list until it encounters element e for which x e is not True. Here we have infinite list of squares 1,4,9,16... and we TAKE those WHILE (<=element) is True starting at the head. Fortunately Haskell is lazy so it only creates as many elements from infinite list as needed for other functions making use of them. Then we check if our element is in list we just created.  Just copy paste (takeWhile (<=n) [ x*x | x <- [1..]]) into GHCI, substitue n for various numbers and see what it returns.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, here's another infinite list version:

```
isSquare n = isSquare' [1..] where
  isSquare' infiniteList@(x:xs)
    | x*x == n  = True
    | x*x > n   = False
    | otherwise = isSquare' xs
```

Comment: `isSqr n=foldr (\x r-> x*x==n || x*x<n && r ) False [1..]`. :)

Comment: @WillNess it could be made even more compact by removing the space between `r` and `)`